# Order of vector norms

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and we have the following inequality norm $\|x\|^2\leq\|y\|^2$. I wonder if this inequality holds after the same linear transformation, i.e., $\|Px\|^2\leq\|Py\|^2$, where $P\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I know this is not true in general, so I want to know under which conditions this holds. For example, if $P$ is positive semi-definite or idempotent.

Expanding the squared norm for the known case we get:
$x^\top x\leq y^\top y$.

Doing the same for the scaled vectors:

$\|Px\|^2=(Px)^\top(Px)=x^\top P^\top P x$,

$\|Py\|^2=(Py)^\top(Py)=y^\top P^\top P y$.

So, would this hold?
$x^\top P^\top P x \leq y^\top P^\top P y$

Comment: A sufficient (but perhaps not necessary) condition for $P$ is to be orthogonal.

I don't know if this observation is useful by any means, but writing $u=y+x$ and $v=y-x$ the initial inequality becomes $u^Tv\ge 0$ and the final one becomes $u^TP^TPv\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

We assume the property holds for all vectors $x$ and $y.$ For $P\neq 0$ the property holds if and  only if $P$ is a constant mutiple of  an orthogonal transformation.
First observe that $\ker P=\{0\}.$ Indeed if $Py=0$ for $\|y\|=1$ and $Px\neq 0$ for $\|x\|=1,$ we get $\|x\|\le \|y\|$ and $\|Px\|>\|Py\|.$

Let $Q=\|Pe_1\|^{-1}P.$ Then $Q$ has the same monotonicity property as $P.$ Thus for  $\|x\|=1=\|e_1\|$ the assumption implies $\|Qx\|=\|Qe_1\|=1.$ Hence $Q$ is orthogonal.

If the vectors $x$ and $y$ are fixed, then the analysis is restricted to two dimensional space.